# Jquery ui - drop is not working all the times

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have been facing a problem with the Jquery UI drag and drop. Please find out my sample code at,

http://jsbin.com/ojaji4

In above sample, There are two droppables. I have set [tolerance: 'pointer'] for droppables. In the middle, there are draggable elements. Now, start dragging element from the left side BLUE square and try to drop it over right side droppable (OR, start dragging element from the right side BLUE square and try to drop it over left side droppable). Both above scenarios, won't work!

Can anybody please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "containment: 'body'" from the draggables, so they can go further then the body.

Comment: Thanks Ryukra, This fixes the problem. But, raises another issues like, 1. horizontal scrollbar comes when starting drag from left and trying to drop onto right dropbox 2. dragged object disappers from the screen while dragging from the right and trying to drop onto left box Ideally, What I aim is.. if [tolerance: 'pointer'] is set then above two problems should not appear; But rather, as soon as mouse pointer comes over droppable then drop should begin